# Add hash to lift menu entry url

Tags: lift

I need something like this

```scala
def sitemap(): SiteMap = SiteMap( Menu.i("Home") / "index#myhash/subhash" )
```

The point is I need add hash to the menu url.  So, the resulting url would be like this

```
<a href="index#myhash/subhash">Home</a> .
```

Is there any way to do it? I need just a temporary solution, so, any idea/hack would help.

thank you

Comment: What doesn't work about that?

Comment: the hash symbol (#) and the slash symbol (/) are url-encoded..

Comment: Agree on the suggestion made on the mailing list..

Comment: Please, paste your anwser (from Lift community), as self-anwser, and mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer I recieved in lift community mail list is that I can't add hash when using sitemap because (as I see) sitemap is intented to be a server side thing that will also catch/match different url locations and help to router them. And since hashes are never sent to server,  SiteMap does not work with hashes at all.

To solve my problem I just built menu links myself (I just added html markup to the page). It was acceptable for my case. In more complicated situation one can use snippet (self-written) to generate the menu in preferable way.